# Не возвращает ветки для коммита

Tags: python, git, githooks

Написал скрипт на python для определения последнего запушенного коммита. Хочу использовать его как pre-receive хук. Делаю пуш, но почему-то после нахождения коммита (1 шаг), не возвращает ветки, которым он принадлежит(возвращает пустую строку). Естественно,вываливается трейсбек и хук не отрабатывает. Пробую вручную в командной строке, ветки возвращает. В чем может быть проблема?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os
import git

for line in sys.stdin: 
  refname = line.split(" ")[2].strip()    
  oldrev = line.split(" ")[0].strip()    
  newrev = line.split(" ")[1].strip()      
  commit = git.get_all_commits(newrev, oldrev)[-1]    
  branches_that_contains_commit = git.get_branches_that_contain_commit(commit)    
 list_of_commits = git.get_all_commits(newrev, branches_that_contains_commit[0], opts=["^%s" % i for i in branches_that_contains_commit[1:]].append("--first-parent"))[-1]    
  last_pushed_commit = git.get_commits_parent(list_of_commits)[1]
```

Comment: может проблема в том, что отличается окружение? распечатайте `os.environ` и сравните.

btw, три строки Вашего кода можно записать короче

    (oldrev, newrev, refname)  = line.split(" ")

правда потом ещё пострипать возможно нужно.

Comment: Вроде не отличаются.Да и я у меня хардкод пока. Есть мысль:
commit = git.get_all_commits(newrev, oldrev)[-1]   - должна возвращать самый ранний коммит из ветки target, возвращает newrev, а так как он не запушен, он не принадлежит пока еще никакой из веток,поэтому и возвращает пустую строку